Multiple case and conditions
I have two tables like this:



collection_id
added_on
edited_on




1
2024-06-19 20:16:41
null


2
2024-06-19 20:17:42
null


3
2024-06-19 20:17:57
null



and



detail_id
collection
detail_type
detail_value




1
1
title
Book title 1


2
1
author
John Doe


3
1
publisher
Publisher A


4
2
title
Book title 2


5
2
author
Jane Doe


6
3
title
Book title 3


7
3
author
John Doe


8
3
publisher
Publisher B



First table is the main table for storing my book collection's ID, and the second table is the collection's details with foreign key 'collection' related to the first table.
I wanted to get the title and author for each book, so I tried:
select 
    collection_id, 
    (case when detail_type = 'title' then detail_value end) as title, 
    (case when detail_type = 'author' then detail_value end) as author
from 
    collections
left join 
    collection_details on collections.collection_id = collection_details.collection
where 
    detail_type = 'title' or detail_type = 'author';

The result is:



collection_id
title
author




1
Book title 1
[null]


1
[null]
John Doe


2
Book title 2
[null]


2
[null]
Jane Doe


3
Book title 3
[null]


3
[null]
John Doe



What I actually expected is:



collection_id
title
author




1
Book title 1
John Doe


2
Book title 2
Jane Doe


3
Book title 3
John Doe



How can I get that desired result with only one query?

Use conditional aggregation by wrapping in max() is one option. I believe postgres might also have a filter option too.

One option would be using FILTER clause.
SELECT  c.collection_id,
        MAX(cd.detail_value) FILTER (WHERE cd.detail_type = 'title') AS title,
        MAX(cd.detail_value) FILTER (WHERE cd.detail_type = 'author') AS author
FROM collections c
LEFT JOIN collection_details cd ON c.collection_id = cd.collection 
GROUP BY c.collection_id
ORDER BY c.collection_id asc;


Alternatively you could use a subquery to get the author and book title
SELECT collection_id, book_author,book_title
FROM collections c
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT collection,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN detail_type = 'author' THEN detail_value END) AS book_author ,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN detail_type = 'title' THEN detail_value END) AS book_title 
           FROM  collection_details 
           GROUP BY collection 
         ) cd on cd.collection=c.collection_id
ORDER BY collection_id asc;

See example

I just realised what I posted is pretty much the same thing as the first example here, just without the grouping+aggregating+filtering for no apparent reason. The filter does nothing since rows were pre-filtered by an identical join condition - I think @Isolated pulled a prank on you with that whole idea. If a single collection could have multiple authors/titles, you'd more likely array_agg() here, rather than show just one.

I addressed that above: "If a single collection could have multiple authors/titles, you'd more likely array_agg() here, rather than show just one. ". The filter does nothing here because you already specified AND cdTitle.detail_type = 'title' when pulling that in, so doing FILTER (WHERE cdTitle.detail_type = 'title') has no effect - by that point all non-titles are already gone from cdTitle. See https://dbfiddle.uk/tm6F_CT7

JOIN the collection_details twice: demo at db<>fiddle
select c.collection_id
      ,t.detail_value as title
      ,a.detail_value as author
from collections as c
left join collection_details as t 
  on c.collection_id = t.collection and t.detail_type='title'
left join collection_details as a
  on c.collection_id = a.collection and a.detail_type='author';




collection_id
title
author




1
Book title 1
John Doe


2
Book title 2
Jane Doe


3
Book title 3
John Doe



Use different aliases and specify the detail_type you want as an additional join condition.

If you allow multiple authors and titles in each collection, you might want to get a string_agg()
select c.collection_id
      ,string_agg(distinct t.detail_value,', ') as titles
      ,string_agg(distinct a.detail_value,', ') as authors
from collections as c
left join collection_details as t 
  on c.collection_id = t.collection and t.detail_type='title'
left join collection_details as a
  on c.collection_id = a.collection and a.detail_type='author'
group by 1;




collection_id
titles
authors




1
Book title 1
John Doe Jr, John Doe Sr


2
Book title 2
Jane Doe


3
Book title 3
John Doe



